# Finding smallest norm vector of an affine space

Tags: linear-algebra

The question I'm trying to solve is:

> Find a polynomial $f \in P_3$ such that $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$ and 
>   $$\int_0^1 |2 + 3t - f(t)|^2 dt$$
>   is as small as possible.

My approach is something along the following lines. For the space $P_3$, we can give it an inner product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t)dt$, so we are interested in minimising $\langle 2+3t-f(t),2+3t-f(t)\rangle$. The conditions $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$ mean that the "constant" term and the "t" term in $f$ are zero, hence the space of 'suitable' $f$ polynomials forms a subspace of $P_3$, which we are shifting by the vector $2+3t$ to get an affine plane, from which we want to find the vector with the smallest norm.

One way I thought about was first extending the set $\{(2+3t)\}$ to a basis, using Gram-Schmidt to get an orthogonal basis (maybe an orthonormal basis if I wanted), but this seems misguided, it doesn't seem to actually help with the problem. Is this what I should be doing, or is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

- Take $f(t)=at^3+bt^2$.
- Integrate. You will get an quadratic expression in terms of $a$ and $b$.
- Take derivative w.r.t. $a$ and $b$ and equate it with $0$.
- Solve for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Rajat's steps are correct, I thought I'd write up what to do. So, you can just compute it:

[image]

But, just to follow up with the idea in the question, you can do a Gram-Schmidt type approach as well (just for fun, it's way more computation, I don't know why I thought it was a good idea). Start with the basis $\{x^3,x^2,x,1\}$, applying Gram-Schmidt to get an orthonormal basis, and then project $2+3x$ onto the directions orthogonal to the $P_3$ subspace to get the solution:

[image]

consistent with the first method.